# 3 Table Join Query

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm curious to know what the best way to query this information with the active record query set for codeigniter.

I have 3 tables:

```
Table 1: "Titles"
         Fields: id, title_name

Table 2: "Roster"
         Fields: id, roster_name

Table 3: "Champions"
         Fields: id, title_id, champion_id, 
                 contender1_id, contender2_id, contender3_id
```

I'm tried doing this before but it just seems like it doesn't get done correctly because issues arise. Any ideas on how the query should be presented?

Any ideas from anyone?

Comment: What field do you use to join `Roster table` and `Champions` ?

Comment: champion_id, contender1_id, contender2_id, and contender3_id

Comment: Actually I want to know do you have any foreign key in the Champions/titles table that is common with roster table. As I guess, you have `title_id` in Champions as common for titles and Champions tables but what is common in roster ?

Comment: No.I don't have any that I know of.

Comment: The one I did it before was rejoined the roster table like 4 times with renaming them each time. Just seems like there has to be an easier way to accomplish this.

Comment: Please post the code you tried.

Comment: I don't have any currently for this. I used to but trying to do it over again since I lost it.

Comment: @user1406861: ActiveRecord aside, what is the resulting query you're hoping to end up with?

Comment: I'm asking for help on how I should create the query.

Comment: We can help you with the query when we know what it is that you need. How do you want to present the data? How are the tables related?